# Visual C++ for a console programmer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I know quite a bit of C++ programming, I know how to use classes, pointers, arrays loops etc. I mainly develop games with C++ which does not require you to know too much visual programming unless you want to make some editor, but now I want to start learning Visual programming with C++ so I wanted to start with visual studio 2010, the problem is that every time I look MS documentation is kind of hard for me to follow it. So my question is, what's a good resource; book or videos, to start learning Visual C++? I don't want something about console programming, what I want is about visual programming with Visual C++. Thanks.

Comment: Visual C++ is a program, you'll have to choose a user interface library. They're all bound to call Windows API but some abstract more, some less, and some allow multiplatform code. What exactly is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: What I meant is a program which includes Forms like in Visual Basic and not a console application because that and with opengl is mainly the way I know how to code in C++

Comment: @pezcode What I want to achieve is to be able to code in C++ with visual studio any type of program. It's just for learning and for future uses, maybe later I will learn C#, but meanwhile I'll stick to C++ because that's what I already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very broad question so I'll try to be as unspecific as possible.
For C++ you have a few choices for interface libraries, you'll have to do some research and decide which one you like most:

- plain Windows API, fun to poke around but masochistic to say the least
- MFC - mostly an OOP wrapper around the Windows API
- WTL is what I would call MFC Lite, another OOP wrapper but very lightweight (alas unsupported by MS)
- Qt is nice if you want to go platform independent but I personally find it very...bloated. Unlike the first few it's not really built around the Windows specifics but a more general approach, very much thought through.

If you decide to stay in the Windows world, I really recommend *Programming Windows* by Charles Petzold. It saved me countless times.

Comment: So what I need to learn is MFC right? I will check out the book but can you recommend any resource on MFC?

Comment: I found most of what I was looking for here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb496952.aspx#C++invisualstudio2010 and thanks for the help, I ordered that book, I think it will help me understand how windows programming works.

Answer (score 1):

For starters on Windows programming and Visual C++, MFC is the best bet. May not be the best framework, but reasoably efficeint and (quite) well designed. As @pezcode mentioned, it is just thin wrapper around Windows API, so there is no or little overhead (as far as "windows" are concerned, and not COM/Sockets/Exception etc.).

More on that MFC is well integrated with VC/VS to do command/message routing right from Resource Editor to the code, which none of the other framework would provide.

Go for it - there are plenty of articles/documentation/sample-code available. DONT dove into Doc/View!

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want to learn how to design graphical-user-interfaces (GUI). So, instead of mucking around with MFC (which is what I think you meant by "visual C++") and the like, I'd recommend learning [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).

**Note:** Visual C++ is the name of Microsoft's C++ compiler. It can be used to create console as well as GUI applications using MS API as well as GUIs with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build visual interfaces using C++, you might want to consider [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/). It's a very good framework for building GUIs and it targets several platforms.

Check the demos to see if that's what you really want.